# How Create Bitcoin wallet from a private key works?

Tags: python, bitcoin, private-key, public-key, wallet

I'm trying to understand how i can create a pair of bitcoin private key and public key and import them in electrum wallet

1 try with : https://github.com/Destiner/blocksmith

for example :

```
 import blocksmith
 
 kg = blocksmith.KeyGenerator()

 kg.seed_input("(/sgroxa)n;[&1ox7fioqg4*v8")
 #seed is the private key ?

 key = kg.generate_key()
 #returned key : 7e659f56d6f20a64258b65445c825e62edf6b89219d4b3eb3ebec6ecb8f62859
 #this key is a formated "(/sgroxa)n;[&1ox7fioqg4*v8" version  ?

 address = blocksmith.BitcoinWallet.generate_address(key)
 #returned address : 112qrCJdHgudHmsKKKwvj3AM3aN2eN9wpP
```

**how to import this in electrum wallet?**

---

2 try : https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools

```
#python38 setup.py install

import os
os.environ['CRYPTOTOOLS_NETWORK'] = 'main'

from cryptotools.BTC import PrivateKey, Address

#private = PrivateKey.random()

mystring='supersecret'.encode('utf-8')
mystring2 = mystring.hex()
private = PrivateKey.from_hex(mystring2)
#private = PrivateKey.random()
print("PRIVATE NOR: "+str(mystring))
print("PRIVATE HEX: "+mystring2)
#private = PrivateKey.from_wif('yourwifhere')

#and then to get the hex representation use private.hex() of private.wif()


public = private.to_public()
print("PUBLIC NOR: "+str(public))
print("PUBLIC HEX: "+public.hex())
#public.hex(compressed=True)

addrp2pkh = public.to_address('P2PKH')
print("ADDR addrp2pkh: "+addrp2pkh)
#'16B2Ghyu5C1CofKfXF2Zi9JycqaAyaE8cd'
addrp2wpkh = public.to_address('P2WPKH')
print("ADDR addrp2wpkh: "+addrp2wpkh)
```

return

```
PRIVATE NOR: b'supersecret'
PRIVATE HEX: 7375706572736563726574
PUBLIC NOR: PublicKey(8168986507460029097250523306678031295706525425592031410379320603875628502471, 68217540890844357698499484021605168903182743958311172870030299256854130530932)
PUBLIC HEX: 04120f7b85fbc8d10d7564fe6dcb99291661014e87d2579068448f8d0b54bf4dc796d1c2869226dfb3609808158d1c4cec9a3a1ebee12994a2779e1d2dac851a74
ADDR addrp2pkh: 15nTqJEGWZg9DTjj7KSjwwKf3xHhpSiQyQ
ADDR addrp2wpkh: bc1q3pv43a0tujsy9kp526su2fz93at70demcj4phw
```

**how to import this in electrum wallet?**

i cant see how i cant key my pub key for import it into electrum wallet for example ?
Cant you help to understand my mistake  or if i confuse something?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.
We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: im just trying to create a pair of private/public key and import them to electrum wallet with python lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices in Electrum:

1. Importing a HD wallet (requires a seed, or mnemonic)
2. Importing a single address (requires the keypair for that address)

#### Importing a HD wallet

Using the `cryptotools` library from your second example:

```
from cryptotools.BTC import Xprv
private = Xprv.from_seed("adfadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaafa")
# private = Xprv.from_mnemonic(...)
print(private.encode()) 
# 'xprv9s21ZrQH143K3RYhJCmDhwpJ4cpXxj7JfUSChYD9rwyZqkTtKb5Y1sc3SzcwgFZ6EiMC38EdQJUKSmc2oni98m3XA8dpnXaMRd8GEQxW6KA'
```

Then in Electrum (from File > New/Restore):

[image: Importing a HD wallet in Electrum]

[image]

[image]

and finish.

#### Importing a single addresses into Electrum using a key pair

[image: Import Bitcoin Addresses dialog in Electrum]

To import an address, Electrum expects users to provide a private key in the [Wallet Import Format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#Base58_Wallet_Import_format) but also prefixed with the type of address (script type: "p2pkh", "p2wpkh", ...) that you wish to recover.

```
from cryptotools.BTC import generate_keypair
private, public = generate_keypair()

wif = private.wif(compressed=True)
print(wif) 
# 'KwcQEum4qYHcfFyWYKsQoRccgnPhhAx1n4b6LfzZVcNA5Eqt8AXP'
```

Then

[image: Importing a single address in Electrum]

[image]

Pasting `KwcQEum4qYHcfFyWYKsQoRccgnPhhAx1n4b6LfzZVcNA5Eqt8AXP` into the Electrum import dialog without a script type in front of it, will default to 'P2PKH', and will import a legacy address (starts with a `1`).

If you are generating a wallet from scratch, you are free to pick any script type you like, 'P2WPKH' being the newest type in use (`bc1` addresses), however if you were actually importing an existing wallet, you would need to make sure this prefix corresponds with the script type that has funds in it.